# node.js/express app hosted with digital ocean displays the Cannot get / error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, digital-ocean

After looking online and seeing countless different answers to different situations, I still couldn't find a solution that worked for me. When I try to run my server.js file locally, it works fine. But when I copy my repository and tried running it in my droplet I get this error:

```
Cannot GET /
```

The following is my server.js code:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback')

const app = express()

const staticFileMiddleware = express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist'))

app.use(staticFileMiddleware)
app.use(history({
  disableDotRule: true,
  verbose: true
}))
app.use(staticFileMiddleware)

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'))
})

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80, function () {
  var port = server.address().port
  console.log('App now running on port', port);
  console.log(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting with an auto-generated express project by doing:

```
npm install -g express-generator
express --view=jade new-project-folder-name
```

... if you do that then `DEBUG=* node bin/www` will launch the project on port 3000 with all debug enabled.

Practically speaking you probably don't actually want to launch your express project on port 80, but rather, you'd want to use a proper web server like Nginx or Apache, and then configure it as a reverse proxy to your express application on a local port (like 3000). Also use UFW to reduce the security surface area of your server.

That way you can also use Lets Encrypt to let the web server manage all the SSL business and leave your express application to just worry about its business.

For a start though, just try launching your project on port 3000 and visiting the site at http://your-ip-address:3000 and see if you get a different result. If you do, you probably need to use the internet to piece together a solution that looks similar to what I described above. Digital Ocean tutorials are pretty good in this regard.

Comment: it says that it cannot find the module , I didnt configure my app to run this way and I am very unfamiliar with that method. Could you explain how you go about running an app with DEBUG=* node bin/www ?

Comment: @Christopher Cannot find the module? Did you `npm install` on your server? `node bin/www` is just what `npm start` does on an automatically generated express project, which I presume you are working with. the prefix `DEBUG=*` sets the DEBUG environment variable, so that express outputs as much diagnostic info as possible while it' running.

Comment: Now that I look at your code again, this isn't an auto-generated project. I'll revise my response. But you should consider changing `process.env.PORT || 80` to `process.env.PORT || 3000`

Comment: all I did was copy my git repository and tried to run my code via my droplet, also it says that all ports are blocked except for port 80 443 and 22

Comment: process.env.PORT || 3000 didnt work out for me. Should I maybe go with the express generator option? would it be a case where it generates a new folder and I would have to move the folders I am trying to serve?

Comment: Depending on how you made the droplet, something might already have ownership of port 80. Open up port 3000 (maybe say something like `ufw allow 3000` and then run the project on port 3000 by saying something (e.g. apache or nginx) like `PORT=3000 node server.js` and see if it works.

Comment: I used a one click install node.js droplet with the latest version of ubuntu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183084/discussion-between-vicatcu-and-christopher).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when I cloned my repository, it didn't push my dist folder. So the solution to my problem was to create a separate repo and push my dist folder manually. I then used this repo to serve my app on my droplet.